# Is there a way to automatically share organizations with their parent organization?

Tags: sharing

I thought this happened automatically but right now when i add a parent organization to an organization, i still have to manually add the portal roles of that parent organization to the sharing settings in order to get them to be shared?

this is with Customer Portal Manager Custom License type

Am I missing something?

Sharing settings are set to private by default with "grant access with hierarchies checked"  and when i login as a contact on the parent organization they can only see that organization by default, not those under it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account hierarchy does not offer any implied sharing, like the way master-detail relationships work in Salesforce. There is a long-standing idea on the IdeaExchange:

[Add more account hierarchy functions for parent/child accounts](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrgnAAC)

The hierarchies in question are the role hierarchies of the user who is the owner of the record. This basically allows implied sharing access to all of the users above the owner of the record in the role hierarchy.

To accomplish what you're trying to achieve, you can either continue manually sharing related accounts when a new parent is assigned or setup sharing with apex and a trigger to automatically share child accounts with contacts/users associated with the parent account.

Comment: Ahh, yea that makes sense.  I guess i just assumed the account hierarchy would also be respected with sharing rules.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you're logging in as a contact, not a User. As a contact, you are not part of a hierarchy. To my recollection, Portal Users, with the exception of Partners, do not have roles and as such, cannot be part of a hierarchy.

Comment: they have roles tho, since they are Customer Portal Manager Custom types. so i can set it up but i have to manually add those roles to the sharing for the child account

Comment: I'll agree that the Portal Manager is a unique situation. But Portal and Community Users in general do not have roles. You might say say that the Portal Manager is at the "top of the heap" in a Portal/Community unless it's a Partner Portal/Community. Generally, roles are implicitly generated/inherited through a contact's owner upon creation as a Portal User. It appears to me that this model is still in flux or development by SF since it's frequently been changing or evolving since the release of Communities.

Comment: Just to clarify here, Partner Communities and Customer Communities Plus licenses do have roles and access to the full sharing model. Only Customer Communities licenses do not have roles and have more limited sharing via sharing sets and groups.